# Where can beginners run their SQL code?If it's a PL,then why it doesn't have a compiler?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I am totally new to the subject of databases and I have only theoretical knowledge about it.I want to run the SQL commands I read about but totally clueless where to run it.The definition says SQL is a special purpose programming language.If so why doesn't it have a compiler?And if I have to install in a RDBMS on my computer to practice SQL, what is the one you would suggest for learners?Can SQL commands be run in all RDBMS?
                   I am totally despondent about it,utterly clueless.Please help me take the first step.Just a simple thing--Where on earth to run those SQL commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to test your queries. There you can chose a database (mysql, Oracle, Sql Server or other), generate test tables, fill them with test data and generate test queries to this data

Comment: Thanks for the link,I am checking it.Let's hope other give their suggestions too.

Comment: @TSingh Welcome to SO :)

Comment: That looks very promising indeed Mr.Voo.Is that enough for those studying database theory (Who only have a chapter or two on SQL)?I am reading that book "Database system concepts" by Korth Silberschatz.Do you feel that site will serve the purpose and that's serves the purpose well?I'll go by whatever you say.I don't want to go very deep as my curriculum doesn't expect me to.I have a dozen other subjects to study--Algorithms,calculus,Compilers.Please give ur final word.That sqlfiddle is enough for my practice?

Comment: It's saying the line "USE mydatabase;" is has error in syntax.I used:

Comment: CREATE DATABASE mydatabase
USE mydatabase;
CREATE TABLE orders
(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
customer VARCHAR(50),
day_of_order DATETIME,
product VARCHAR(50),
quantity INT);

Comment: @TSingh It is enough in general to work with most basic SQL. But I advice you to install some kind of database on your own machine for making your experiments. It can be freeware MySql or SQL Server Express or Oracle Express, and work with them. The should give you a deeper understanding of working with data.

Comment: @TSingh There is a number of limitations there - you can't create databases, build indexes and many other things (remove "CREATE DATABASE mydatabase USE mydatabase" - just chose in upper left corner). You can simulate table creation, filing it with data and quering it

Comment: Last thing--Do different RDBMS like MySql,Oracle Express etc all follow the SQL standard, does it mean they all have the DDL and DML commands?Or each vendor has some commands unique to its product?I ask because even a simple command like "CREATE DATABASE voo" is showing error in syntax in that sqlfiddle.Can you give me a sample code that runs successfully there?That will be my first run of a successful SQL Command!!

Comment: @TSingh Well, DDL and DML SQL standarts are mostly the same for all RDBMS (sometimes you can see a small differences in syntax of commands). The important differences you will see if you start deep learning of working with each of them, but mostly the are not SQL syntax. First query, well, chose SQL Server 2008 and past you query - CREATE TABLE orders (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, customer VARCHAR(50), day_of_order DATETIME, product VARCHAR(50), quantity INT); then click Build Schema button

Comment: WOOO HOOO!!!IT WORKED!!Thanks.First step!!

Comment: Can you tell me why your code doesn't work for MySQL but works fine for SQL Server 2008?Is it due to the fact that all vendors don't follow SQL strictly and have slight variations in their own version of SQL?I mean, else your code would have worked across all RDBMS listed in that list in that site.Kindly explain this much.

Comment: @TSingh yes, you understood it right. Usually in practise you work with 1 kind of RDBMS and you know it syntax well. But other RDBMS may have some variations, and your example shows that. MySql doesn't support identity, so removing it query will work - CREATE TABLE orders (id INT PRIMARY KEY, customer VARCHAR(50), day_of_order DATETIME, product VARCHAR(50), quantity INT);

Comment: As you said I have installed Oracle Express Edition 10g.It works fine.Will it be a proper foundation for me if I learn SQL on it,then PL/SQL and then make Oracle Express the first database that I know how to handle?I read 70% corporations use Oracle and that it has even bought MySQL.So is it wise  for a beginner to choose Oracle database over others to practice?Though my intuition says so,I want you to confirm.

Comment: @TSingh Yes, Oracle is one of two DataBase main monsters. It is a good start for you. The basics of Oracle a suit for other databases, to studing it is a way to go.

Comment: Glad that you are online.Since SO warns me that I have extended the comments,hence I put my confusion in a new question.Please answer it there in detail.I shall be grateful to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832172/is-it-advisable-for-a-beginner-to-choose-oracle-database-10g-pl-sql-as-his-first

Comment: @TSingh well, such questions, as you ask are not suitable for this site. You should probably ask them http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or maybe http://ux.stackexchange.com/. Here you should ask about more certain problems about how to write some SQL code